# get html from a variable by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

i have a variable name value in my javascript code that contain html data.i want to get the data inside form specific id  that is inside #myDiv

```
  var value="<div >
             <p class="">Hi cname@gmail.com</p>
             <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div id="myDiv">
              sgdhsagdhagh
              dhsajdgasj
              cjzjcg
              </div>

            </div>"
```

Thanks

Comment: `$(value).filter('#myDiv').html()`

Comment: it will work like this $(value).find('#myDiv').html()

thanks anyway

Comment: Consider accepting the answer which helped you most, thats the best way to say thanks see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

You should create a DOM element, then traverse up to it and get `html()` or `.text()`

```js
  var value = '<div >\
             <p class="">Hi cname@gmail.com</p>\
             <br/>\
            <br/>\
            <div id="myDiv">\
              sgdhsagdhagh\
              dhsajdgasj\
              cjzjcg\
              </div>\
            </div>';

  alert($(value).find('#myDiv').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to get parent element, then use

```
alert($('<div />', {html: value}).find('#myDiv').html())
```

Comment: Will not work if OP want main parent/container element. Use `filter('#myDiv')` in that case.

Comment: @Tushar, In that case I will prefer `alert($('<div />', {html: value}).find('#myDiv').html())`

Answer (score 2):

How about you do like this?

```
var variable = "stuff n things";
document.getElementById( 'myDiv' ).innerHTML = variable;
```

Thats the native way :)

EDIT:

if you want to get the data you just do like this:

```
var variable = document.getElementById( 'myDiv' ).innerHTML;
```

That will give you the markup of whats inside the div.

Or use `document.querySelector("#myDiv")` to get the first match on the `selector.querySelectorAll` returns array.

Comment: Question was " want to get the data inside form specific id that is inside #myDiv", this does exactly that

Comment: @25r43q actually this doesn't. The variable contains the HTML, and from that HTML he wants to get the content of a certain ID.

Comment: @PierreDuc what? Ok, I'll try to expand my answer.

Comment: @25r43q the problem is that the `HTML` is not (yet) attached to the document. So `document.getElementById` won't work

Comment: if the js is below the markup there is no need for document ready functions, if the js is triggered by an event the html will also exist. Has the OP specified how the js is triggered?

Comment: @Pierreduc, until the OP specifies further it will only be guesswork reg his actual intentions. He now has several methods to get and set the data (whichever he intends). I consider the matter closed and the question to be answered.

Comment: @25r43q For me his intentions were clear, but thanks for the downvote though. Serves me well I guess

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML of the `value` variable to create an `jQuery` object. From this object you can search for the element with the `id`, and get its HTML content:

```
var html = $(value).find('#myDiv').html();
console.log(html); //sgdhsagdhaghdhsajdgasjcjzjcg
```

Or a pure javascript implementation:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = value;
var html = el.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML;
console.log(html); //sgdhsagdhaghdhsajdgasjcjzjcg
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using plain `Javascript`use:**

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
```

**Using `jQuery`:**

```
$("#myDiv").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are Two ways- **Angular way-**

```
var elem = angular.element(value);
var innerDive=elem[0].getElementById('myDiv');
var text= angular.element(innerDive[0]).innerText;
```

**Jquery-**

```
var text= $(value).find('#myDiv').text();
```